# using Cast 3D error 1046: Matrix 3D whats its meaning?

Tags: flash, ado

I am trying to use CAST3D in flash and when i execute the code its giving me this 
error 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Matrix3D. When i click on the compiler error it takes me to an actionScript of the CAST3D which is this:

public function get local(): Matrix3D { return this.geomgroup.transform; }

I have already installed the library.swc file in flash. Im new to flash.
Is there any solution to this problem ? 
thanks alot
Adrian De Barro

```
public function blenderModel() 
    {
        setup3DScene();
    }
private function setup3DScene(): void
    {
        this.setupSandy();
        this.setupCast3D();
        this.setupControls();
        this.loadData();

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.handleEnterFrame);    
    }

    /**
     * initial setup for Sandy3D.
     */     
    public function setupSandy(): void
    {       
     // We create the camera
         camera = new Camera3D( 600, 400 );
         camera.near = 1;

         // We create the "group" that is the tree of all the visible objects
         var root:Group = new Group();

         // We create a Scene and we add the camera and the objects tree 
         scene = new Scene3D( "scene", this, camera, root );             
         scene.light = new Light3D(new Vector(0,0,1),100);
    }

    /**
     * initial setup for Cast3D.
     */     
    public function setupCast3D(): void
    {       
                    this.loaded = false;
        this.animator = new Cast3d(this.scene, this.camera);
        this.animator.animationType = Cast3d.ANIMATION_TYPE_BYFRAME; //  ANIMATION_TYPE_REAL; //
        this.animator.fps = 22;
        this.animator.autoRewind = false;                       
    }

    /**
     *  Function setups visual animation control
```

Comment: that's a pretty fundamental unit of a 3D engine. Please show how you are creating your scene/object

Comment: i put the necessary code i didnt put the load and controls methos

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this library and from a brief look at the documentation I'm not 100% clear on how it interacts with Papervision3D or Sandy3D. However, the [tutorials page](http://www.cast3d.org/tutorials) lists the following requirement next to a download link for a single Cast3D swc:

- Flex Library cast3d.swc code built with rendering engine Sandy3D or
  Papervision3D.

As Sunil points out, the error is telling you that the compiler cannot find the Matrix3D class. However, I think it's a Matrix3D class in the Sandy3D library rather than the version built in to Flash player. I think you need to download the correct version of Sandy3D and ensure that it is referenced correctly in your compiler options.

Comment: good call... I just checked the docs for Sandy3D, but it defines a class called Matrix4 (4x4 matrix) for 3D transformations. But low and behold, Papervision3D has a Matrix3D class!

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that your compiler cannot find the [Matrix3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html) class, which is a class that is built into Flash Player versions 10.0 and higher.

Is it possible that the compiler settings for your project are specifying Flash 9, and therefore it doesn't know about the `Matrix3D` class?